# Members-only page, but accessible via sharable link

Tags: plugins, permalinks, password, membership

Our site has a lot of members-only content, but we would like to allow our members to share certain content with non-members. Is there a way to generate sharable links that would allow non-members to access this restricted content?

Comment: I don't think you have provided enough info for anyone to accurately answer your question.  How this members only content locked down?  Assuming you are using a plugin for this?

Comment: @RiddleMeThis This content is locked down to our "users". When someone signs up, they are added to our users. No plugin is used.

We can elect to "Make Public" certain pages, but then it's open to everyone. We're trying to keep everything private, but allow access with a sharable link.

Answer (score 0):

Can be done easily with a shortcode:

```
[members-only]...content...[/members-only]
```

The shortcode will return content for members, or text '`<h3>This is for members only!</h3>`', for non member request. The callback function of the shortcode will check who made a request, and return  display data accordingly. Any other text on page/post will be displayed as is. For more info about shortcodes see: [Shotcodes API](https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API)

Comment: Is there a way to embed the shortcode into the email? We've already got the content locked down to members only, but I need to know how to send a link to non-members so they can view the locked down content.

Comment: Your website cannot communicate with not registered users (email). I understand that your site is not public, so only registered users can view it. Open it to public, and control (shortcode) who can see what,